# JSP/servlet version in WAS 8?

Tags: websphere

Which version of JSP/servlet is in websphere 8? I use IBM RAD 8 with websphere 8 and wonder whether the JSP/servlet container supports method calls in EL which "the latest" servlet containers are supposed to do. Can it?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Specifications and API documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rovr_specs.html) in the InfoCenter, WebSphere v8 supports JEE6, Java Servlet 3.0, and JSP 2.2.

Answer (score 6):

WebSphere 8/8.5/8.5.5 has support for same Servlet ( 3.0 ), JSP ( 2.2 ) and JSF ( 2.0 ) versions. Only change is in JDBC version, which you may not that dependent.

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_WebSphere_Application_Server#Version_history

Side note: IBM start having internal ibm-web-bnd and ibm-web-ext files having extension xm**l** instead of xm**i** since Servlet/WebApp version **2.5** declared in web.xml

Refer below chart.

[image]